# ASP.NET MVC 4, EF, SQL Server 2014 Express more users jQuery get request take 4s instead of 42ms

Tags: c#, jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

http://robertgaut.com/Blog/2003/Getting-Started-MVC-4-Entity-Framework-5-Code-First-and-Unity

If only one user is logged in everything works fast and smoothly.

For example, jQuery get request takes 420ms.

If more users are logged in, the same jQuery get request takes 4s.

How to find out where the problem is?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF as is described in first link with `PerRequestLifetimeManager`. Database is SQL Server 2014 Express. Where to start searching my problem?

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
;
```

[image]

EDIT:

**- Debugging is disabled by web.config**

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"></compilation>
```

**- Threads per processor limit**

set as 50

**- Queue Length for pool is set as default: 1000**

[image]

**- http compression**

is set to true in IIS

[image]

and also globally as

in `%WinDir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` contains:

```
<system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />       
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
</system.webServer>
```

**- max connections limit**

no idea where to set it

Comment: What about your IIS settings? Have you checked those - like disable debugging, threads per processor limit, queue length, http compression, max connections limit?

Comment: Singleton on the datacontext ?

Comment: IMHO: 420ms !== "fast & smooth"

Comment: @nizzik I edited question. Where to set 'max connections limit' and 'threads per processor limit'?

Comment: @Florian F. we are using datacontext

Comment: @Robert but 420ms is much much faster then 4.2s :)

Comment: @nizzk any idea if everything is ok?